# New Quote id generate on every time of getQuote() in magento

Tags: php, magento, quote

When i try to get cart items by using getQuote() method like

**Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();**

It generates new quote id on every time of this line call. **sales_flat_quote** table growing rapidly & it will make a looping! And show the below error! plz check the screenshot!

**Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '6000' reached, aborting!**

[image]

This issue occurs only some times and for some customers only. If i check in another system, Its showing fine! It rectify automatically after some times. But I can't understand why it happening.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Disabled XDebug and you will be fine.

This error message comes specifically from the XDebug extension. PHP itself does not have a function nesting limit. Change [the setting](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level) in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 10000
```

or in your PHP code:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 10000);
```

As for if you really need to change it (i.e.: if there's a alternative solution to a recursive function), I can't tell without the code.